# Tomcat Multiple Datasources with decrypt password logic

Tags: java, datasource, tomcat8.5

I am facing some issues with while working with multiple datasources in Tomcat environment. Please find the details below.
I have below 2 datasources in my tomcat/conf/server.xml file

Data Source1:

```
<Resource name="myds1" 
          global="myds1"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="com.tomcat.datasorceEncrypt.EncryptedDataSourceFactory"
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
          singleton = "false"/>
```

Data Source2:

```
<Resource name="myds2" 
          global="myds2"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="com.tomcat.datasorceEncrypt.EncryptedDataSourceFactory"
          driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
          singleton = "false"/>
```

Here is my `EncryptedDataSourceFactory` file which extends `DataSourceFactory`:

```
package com.tomcat.datasorceEncrypt;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.Name;
import javax.naming.RefAddr;
import javax.naming.Reference;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.juli.logging.Log;
import org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolConfiguration;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.XADataSource;

public class EncryptedDataSourceFactory extends DataSourceFactory {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(EncryptedDataSourceFactory.class);

    private static final String PROP_DIALECT = "dialect";
    private static final String[] CUSTOM_PROPERTIES = new String[]{PROP_DIALECT};
    private static final String[] PROPERTIES = Stream.of(ALL_PROPERTIES, CUSTOM_PROPERTIES).flatMap(Stream::of).toArray(String[]::new);


    @Override
    public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable<?, ?> environment)
            throws Exception {
         if (obj != null && obj instanceof Reference) {
             Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
             Properties properties = new Properties();

             for (int i = 0; i < PROPERTIES.length; ++i) {
                 String propertyName = PROPERTIES[i];
                 RefAddr ra = ref.get(propertyName);
                 if (ra != null) {
                     String propertyValue = ra.getContent().toString();
                     properties.setProperty(propertyName, propertyValue);
                 }
             }

             return this.createDataSource(properties, nameCtx,false);
         } else {
             return null;
         }
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource createDataSource(Properties properties, Context context, boolean XA) throws Exception {
        // Here we decrypt our password.
        PoolConfiguration poolProperties = parsePoolProperties(properties);
        Properties dbProperties = loadProperties();
        poolProperties.setPassword(CryptoUtility.decryptDBPass(dbProperties.getProperty("DB_key"), dbProperties.getProperty("DB_password")));
        poolProperties.setUsername(dbProperties.getProperty("DB_username"));
        poolProperties.setUrl(dbProperties.getProperty("DB_url"));
        System.out.println(poolProperties.getPoolName() + "****-------*****" + poolProperties.getName() );
        System.out.println(poolProperties.getDataSourceJNDI() + "****------***" + poolProperties.getDataSource());
        // The rest of the code is copied from Tomcat's DataSourceFactory.
        if (poolProperties.getDataSourceJNDI() != null && poolProperties.getDataSource() == null) {
            performJNDILookup(context, poolProperties);
        }
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource = XA ? new XADataSource(poolProperties)
                : new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource(poolProperties);
        dataSource.createPool();

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties loadProperties() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("DBPassword.properties");
            prop.load(inputStream);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.fatal("Error Loading the properties.", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return prop;
    }

}
```

I was trying to identify the datasource JNDI name from `poolProperties.getDataSourceJNDI()` so that I can apply proper credentials through my properties, but I am receiving `poolProperties.getDataSourceJNDI()` as null.

Have I missed any property in the Resource while creating datasource?

Note: While working with resource I could able to set user name and password though I have got `poolProperties.getDataSourceJNDI()` is null.

Comment: Does it work for you if using single datasource?

Comment: Yes it worked , but I do see getDataSourceJNDI() value was null

Answer (score 0):

For timebeeing I have created one more class by extending DatasourceFactory for second datasource, it's working but I don't think it's an Idle solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the routine, getObjectInstance, the parameter name can be used for this.
Based on the name, the decrypt method can be called for different data sources.
I had 8 datasources defined. I used this approach so that I just use one DataSourcefactory class.